# Disable debug messages from specific assembly

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, avalondock

I have a C# application with NLog for logging and it's set up to also log messages sent to System.Diagnostics's Trace/Debug system. This is done in the application's config file like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="2">
    <listeners>
      <add name="nLogListener" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>

  <sources>
    <!--bunch of extra sources here-->
  </sources>

  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="nLogListener" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog"/>
  </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This works all nicely, but since I started using AvalonDock the logs get cluttered with debugging info. I guess the assembly, pulled in via nuGet, was compiled with the `DEBUG` constant defined so the calls to Deug.WriteLine that are all over the AvalonDock source make it to the NLog log eventually. They look like this btw:

```
NLog.LoggerImpl.Write | Attach() 
NLog.LoggerImpl.Write | DockingManager.OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(System.Windows.Controls.Canvas) 
NLog.LoggerImpl.Write | SetFocusOnLastElement(focused=True, model=Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable, element=System.Windows.Controls.Canvas) 
NLog.LoggerImpl.Write | DockingManager.OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(System.Windows.Controls.Canvas)
```

I'd like to exclude them while still maintaining all other messages sent to the trace. I could add a filter to NLog to exclude all of them using wildcards etc, but I'd rather don't do that since:

- it requires me to figure out all possible messages AvalonDock can spit out
- if AvalonDock changes, I have to update the filter
- there's a risk of also excluding non-AvalonDock messages

Is there another way to handle this (without recompiling AvalonDock's source)? Can I somehow exclude all messages originating from a specific assembly? Or maybe have them prefixed with a known string so I can filter messages based on a single string?

Comment: There are some interesting notes in somewhat [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4144394/395718).

Comment: There's interesting info in remarks section of [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) class.

Comment: @Dialecticus interesting indeed but unfortunately AvalonDock doesn't use `TraceSource`s but plain `Debug.WriteLine`, so I don't think the info applies to this case?