# Google Picasa Service - Turn Off Logging

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-api, gdata, picasa

I am using .NET library of the google Picasa and when I execute the below code.

```
    Dim requestFactory As GOAuth2RequestFactory = RefreshAuthenticate(accessToken, refreshToken)

    Dim service As New PicasaService("test")
    service.RequestFactory = requestFactory

    Dim query As New AlbumQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri("default"))
    Dim feed As PicasaFeed = service.Query(query)
```

It generates HELL of logging (I guess using Trace.Write).
Our application uses trace listeners and save that tracing to text files (log files). but with this single call, over 10s of Mbs log is generated. 
I want to turn off the logging for Google Picasa (preferably with code).

I see an article on [Debugging Google Data API Clients: Exploring Traffic from Within your Program](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/debugging_client_libs#java) But that doesn't say anything about turning that off.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
 Thank you

Comment: I don't think anyone is supporting the gdata client library anymore.  Most of the APIs that it supports are dead.   I think the source for it is hear https://github.com/google/google-gdata  maybe you could pick it apart.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993(v=vs.110).aspx) contains ways of both removing trace listeners and filtering them in your own config so you don't need to rely upon third party apis to implement an on / off feature.

Comment: Well, I don't want to remove trace listeners as my application itself is producing lot of trace information I must keep. I just want the Google APIs to stop producing traces.

Comment: I'm not suggesting removing them globally, just removing them for the picasa logging source. Here's another article which explains things a bit better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144394/turning-tracing-off-via-app-config

Comment: Well, I tried to remove the default trace listener and kept mine as it is. But it is captured by my trace listener and keep logging that big log. I dont think Google is categorizing the trace writing. Its too late for me to add switches to my trace listeners as I have too big code now.